# "Choose File" button did not work after I changed permission

Tags: java, android, permissions, camera

Hi my project requires me to work with webview and camera. I implemented codes in HTML which upon pressing a "Choose File" button, the webview will let me choose whether to capture photo using camera or upload files from my file manager. But I don't want the file option, I just want it to launch camera right after I press the button. This is the code where it asks for permission to use my camera and external storage

```
public void get_file(){
    String[] perms = {/*Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, */Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

    //Checking for CAMERA Permissions first
    //if (ASWP_CAMUPLOAD && check_permission(3)) {
        //ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, file_perm);

    //Checking for storage permission to write images for upload
    if (ASWP_FUPLOAD && ASWP_CAMUPLOAD && !check_permission(2) && !check_permission(3)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, perms, file_perm);

    //Checking for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
    } else if (ASWP_FUPLOAD && !check_permission(2)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, file_perm);

    //Checking for CAMERA permissions
    } else if (ASWP_CAMUPLOAD && !check_permission(3)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, file_perm);
    }
}
public boolean check_permission(int permission){
    switch(permission){
        case 1:
            return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

        case 2:
            return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

        case 3:
            return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    }
    return false;
}
```

And this is the code that I changed

```
static boolean ASWP_FUPLOAD     = false;     //upload file from webview
static boolean ASWP_ONLYCAM     = true ;     //only use camera as input
```

I changed the upload file from webview option from true to false. But weird thing is, after I changed it to false, pressing the button never worked anymore. What did I do wrong? If I want to use camera only should I remove some of the lines in public void get_file() ? 
Hoping for some advises, thank you!
Edit: I found one code which is ASWP_ONLYCAM that only enables camera as the only input! But I have no idea how to activate it!
p.s. please let me know if you need anymore info

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly does the `check_permission()` method do? Could you provide us the code?

Comment: @C0nverter Hi so sorry about that! I added and please have a look!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are using [Android SmartWebView](https://github.com/mgks/Android-SmartWebView/).

I suppose that you support yourself with code from [here (ProgramCreek)](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=mgks%2FAndroid-SmartWebView%2FAndroid-SmartWebView-master%2Fapp%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fmgks%2Finfeeds%2Fwebview%2FMainActivity.java), as your methods are so far the same. if so, **both `ASWP_FUPLOAD` and `ASWP_CAMUPLOAD` need to be `true`**, as `ASWP_CAMUPLOAD` depends on `ASWP_FUPLOAD`.

Then, you need to go inside `MainActivity`. Inside `asw_view.setWebChromeClient()` you should have these voids:

```java
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
```

```java
public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
```

There is the logic for your photo management. First is compatible with Android API 16+, second one is with 21+.

Now, as of API 16+ (first method), I can't see a direct solution. You could use the one from [this thread](/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent). The second method though is easily editable. You have `if` statements verifying `ASWP_CAMUPLOAD` and `ASWP_FUPLOAD`. At the end of `ASWP_CAMUPLOAD` verification, you have this:

```java
if(ASWP_CAMUPLOAD) {
    //...
} else {
    intentArray = new Intent[0];
}
```

`return false` instead, so file upload itself should be cancelled, and camera upload will become an only solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I lost myself from "Now, as of API 16+..." What do I need to modify to solve my problem? I'm so sorry I'm not very strong in programming ><

Comment: Wait I kinda get it, so I should return false at the end of the ASWP_CAMUPLOAD loop right?

Comment: `openFileChooser()` is your method for older Android versions. API 16 is probably around Android 4.x. You can try to understand the code here to see, how the file is retrieved, and use thread I've provided you, to modify this method.

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind, that this will work for Android API 21+. Devices with Android under Lollipop will still have a choice between file and camera.

Comment: ah alright, I'll have a read first and if I don't understand, is there any better way to contact you?

Comment: Sure! You can write to me at `m.kramek@outlook.com`.